# tkz-euclide commands changing the position of a tikzfigure - need it to stop

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

It's rare that I go to find a solution to a problem on ChatGPT and Google, and find absolutely nothing that even remotely mentions the problem. Maybe I'm just terrible at searching.

In the following code, I have four minipages displaying different types of triangles. Using tkx-euclide commands in the isosceles and equilateral triangles (but not scalene). It is centering both of those diagrams and vertically shifting them. I don't want them centered, nor do I want them vertically shifted. So I need a solution to the problem. I think the \tkzLabelAngle commands are causing the issue, but I need a way to use that command without the positioning issues.

Thanks

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\linewidth}
    \textsf{\textbf{Scalene Triangle}}
    \newline\newline
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) -- (1,2) -- (3,1.75) -- (0,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\linewidth}
    \textsf{\textbf{Isosceles Triangle}}
    \newline\newline
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (B) at (4,0);
            \coordinate (C) at (2,1.5);
            \draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (2,1.5) -- (0,0);
            \tkzMarkSegment[color=black,pos=.5,mark=|](A,C)
            \tkzMarkSegment[color=black,pos=.5,mark=|](B,C)
            \tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.33](C,A,B){$\circ$}
            \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.33](C,B,A){$\circ$}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\newline\newline
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\linewidth}
    \textsf{\textbf{Equilateral Triangle}}
    \newline\newline
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (B) at (3,0);
            \coordinate (C) at (1.5,{1.5*sqrt(3)});
            
            \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
            \tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.33](C,A,B){$\circ$}
            \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.33](C,B,A){$\circ$}
            \tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.33](B,C,A){$\circ$}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\linewidth}
    \textsf{\textbf{Right Triangle}}
    \newline\newline
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Probably similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/463535/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to draw them all in a single tikz picture with different `scope` and locate them with different `shift` value. I believe the nagtive `pos` key value could cause larger bounding box. It's better to use positive value if possible.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,2) -- (3,1.75) -- cycle;
\node at (1.5,2) [above=0.5cm] {\textsf{\textbf{Scalene Triangle}}};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4,0);
\coordinate (C) at (2,1.5);
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (2,1.5) -- cycle;
\tkzMarkSegment[color=black,pos=.5,mark=|](A,C)
\tkzMarkSegment[color=black,pos=.5,mark=|](B,C)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.33](C,A,B){$\circ$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.33](C,B,A){$\circ$}
\node at (C)  [above=1cm] {\textsf{\textbf{Isosceles Triangle}}};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,0);
\coordinate (C) at (1.5,{1.5*sqrt(3)});
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.33](B,A,C){$\circ$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.33](C,B,A){$\circ$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.33](A,C,B){$\circ$}
\node at (C) [above=0.5cm] {\textsf{\textbf{Equilateral Triangle}}};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(6.5cm,-4cm)}]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,0);
\coordinate (C) at (3,{1.5*sqrt(3)});
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\node at (1.5,{1.5*sqrt(3)}) [above=0.5cm] {\textsf{\textbf{Right Triangle}}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

##############################################################################

> Here is an example shows that negative `pos` value enlarge the bounding box. The same drawing but the nagetive `pos` value make the bottom left and top angle have a larger bounding box.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,0);
\coordinate (C) at (1.5,{1.5*sqrt(3)});
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.33](B,A,C){$\circ$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.33](C,B,A){$\circ$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.33](A,C,B){$\circ$}
\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,0);
\coordinate (C) at (1.5,{1.5*sqrt(3)});
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.33](C,A,B){$\circ$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.33](C,B,A){$\circ$}
\tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.33](B,C,A){$\circ$}
\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> Use `minipage` with positive `pos` value and `\noindent` for the first line. Did the output match what you expected? I use `report` document class as an example and show the frame for the page.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\linewidth}
    \textsf{\textbf{Scalene Triangle}}
    \newline\newline
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) -- (1,2) -- (3,1.75) -- (0,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\linewidth}
    \textsf{\textbf{Isosceles Triangle}}
    \newline\newline
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (B) at (4,0);
            \coordinate (C) at (2,1.5);
            \draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (2,1.5) -- (0,0);
            \tkzMarkSegment[color=black,pos=.5,mark=|](A,C)
            \tkzMarkSegment[color=black,pos=.5,mark=|](B,C)
            \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.33](B,A,C){$\circ$}
            \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.33](C,B,A){$\circ$}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\newline\newline
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\linewidth}
    \textsf{\textbf{Equilateral Triangle}}
    \newline\newline
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
            \coordinate (B) at (3,0);
            \coordinate (C) at (1.5,{1.5*sqrt(3)});
            
            \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
            \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.33](B,A,C){$\circ$}
            \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.33](C,B,A){$\circ$}
            \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.33](A,C,B){$\circ$}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\linewidth}
\textsf{\textbf{Right Triangle}}
\newline\newline
\begin{tikzpicture}
            
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. First solution. You don't work specifically with tkz-euclide. You mix with TikZ and it's not good.

You don't use negative values for `pos` because as Tom says: you're making the bounding box bigger.

With clip you can control the bbox (see 2 )

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,3/0/B}
        \tkzDefTriangle[equilateral](A,B)\tkzGetPoint{C}
        \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.33](B,A,C){$\circ$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.33](C,B,A){$\circ$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.33](A,C,B){$\circ$}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

2. You can control the bbox with `\tkzClipPolygon(A,B,C)`

   ```
   \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (3,0);
        \coordinate (C) at (1.5,{1.5*sqrt(3)});
        \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
        \tkzClipPolygon(A,B,C)
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.33](C,A,B){$\circ$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.33](C,B,A){$\circ$}
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.33](B,C,A){$\circ$}
    \end{tikzpicture}
   ```